# No sound with Rpi 2

Tags: pi-2, ubuntu

I am using Rpi2 installed with ubuntu mate.I've got [these](http://www.giftease.com/featured-products/philips-spa-60-multimedia-speaker-red) speakers but when I plug into the audio 3.5mm jackout there is no response from speakers. The speakers are working fine with other devices.Is it some driver problem or something else with ubuntu mate?.

PS: Ubuntu mate does not have raspi-config feature

Comment: Have a look at this https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/audio-config.md you may need to modify the config file to switch audio output to the av jack since the default is to output sound through the HDMI cable.

Comment: @SteveRobillard - Thank you for your reply but I don't have raspbian installed I have ubuntu mate which does not have raspi-config support

Comment: Then this is not a raspberry pi question, since your audio does work on the Pi Hardware. Please ask on Ubuntu Exchange or maybe... you speakers are broken.....?

Comment: My speakers are working with other devices please read the question again. The problem is that there is no raspi-config to work with or I don't know how to force my audio-out through 3.5mm audio jack.

Comment: This might be caused by the HDMI audio output being selected. According to [abishur](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=40872) you can change this with: `sudo amixer cset numid=3 1`.

Comment: Thankyou @Thor my speakers are working fine after running that command, thankyou for your solution if you make this answer please explain what exactly this command does and what is amixer Thankyou once again! :D

Comment: @Creator: glad it helped, I posted a more portable version as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### tl;dr

Most likely the Pi is routing the audio through the HDMI port, run the following command to make it use the 3.5mm plug output:

```
amixer cset name='PCM Playback Route' 1
```

#### more detailed answer

Out of the box, the Pi has 2 audio sinks or outputs: HDMI and the 3.5mm plug, if a display is connected the Pi defaults to using HDMI audio. You can change the routing of the audio with `amixer` from the alsa-utils package.

The `amixer` program can be used to list and edit various audio settings, e.g. listing controls:

```
amixer controls
```

Output:

```
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Route'
numid=2,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Switch'
numid=1,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Volume'
numid=5,iface=PCM,name='IEC958 Playback Con Mask'
numid=4,iface=PCM,name='IEC958 Playback Default'
```

Getting the value of `PCM Playback Route`:

```
amixer cget name='PCM Playback Route'
```

Output:

```
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Route'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw------,values=1,min=0,max=2,step=0
  : values=0
```

Only the bottom line is interesting here. The numbers that `values` takes mean the following:

- 0 = auto
- 1 = 3.5mm plug
- 2 = HDMI

So to set the Pi to use the mini-jack plug, run the following command:

```
amixer cset name='PCM Playback Route' 1
```

Output:

```
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Route'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw------,values=1,min=0,max=2,step=0
  : values=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an update to do the same with console-based `raspi-config` gui:

In **terminal** type:

```
sudo raspi config
```

chose `Advanced Options`

chose `Audio`

chose `Force 3.5mm`

accept with `ok` then `finish`.

Comment: The command needs to be `sudo raspi-config`.